# Calculate duration while counting overlapping years once only

Tags: r

I have a large job-exposure database, and I want to calculate the duration of exposure of each subject to each agent. But a subject can be exposed to an agent through different jobs. For each job, I have the start year and end year. But my problem is that there are overlapping periods between the jobs, and I want to find the total duration of exposure to the agent with R while counting for the overlapping years only once (If I count it in job1, I don't want to recount it in job 2). I added  a data (can be called dat) that can be used. For example with the subject 2, he was exposed to agent A through his job1 and  job2 and we have the YEARIN and YEAROUT for each job, but there is a 3 years overlap between the 2 jobs (1998-2000)

| ID | JOB | AGENT | YEARIN | YEAROUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | A | 1998 | 2009 |
| 2 | 2 | A | 1996 | 2000 |
| 2 | 7 | B | 1979 | 1985 |
| 2 | 8 | B | 1978 | 1982 |
| 7 | 1 | B | 1973 | 2006 |
| 7 | 1 | A | 1973 | 2006 |
| 15 | 1 | A | 1979 | 2007 |
| 18 | 1 | D | 1976 | 1985 |
| 18 | 2 | D | 1980 | 2008 |
| 18 | 4 | D | 1970 | 2005 |
| 18 | 2 | A | 1978 | 1979 |
| 18 | 3 | A | 1984 | 1995 |
| 20 | 3 | C | 1988 | 1993 |
| 20 | 4 | C | 1996 | 2002 |
| 20 | 6 | C | 2000 | 2008 |

I wanted to use the function mutate and aggregate but I'm not sure how to take into account the overlapping years.

Comment: Please add your data using the `dput()` function in `R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat <- tibble::tribble(
~ID,    ~JOB,   ~AGENT, ~YEARIN,    ~YEAROUT,
2,  1,  "A",    1998,   2009,
2,  2,  "A",    1996,   2000,
2,  7,  "B",    1979,   1985,
2,  8,  "B",    1978,   1982,
7,  1,  "B",    1973,   2006,
7,  1,  "A",    1973,   2006,
15, 1,  "A",    1979,   2007,
18, 1,  "D",    1976,   1985,
18, 2,  "D",    1980,   2008,
18, 4,  "D",    1970,   2005,
18, 2,  "A",    1978,   1979,
18, 3,  "A",    1984,   1995,
20, 3,  "C",    1988,   1993,
20, 4,  "C",    1996,   2002,
20, 6,  "C",    2000,   2008)


dat %>% 
  group_by(ID, JOB, AGENT) %>% 
  summarise(year = seq(YEARIN, YEAROUT, by=1)) %>% 
  unnest(year) %>% 
  group_by(ID, AGENT) %>% 
  summarise(nyear = length(unique(year)))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'ID', 'JOB', 'AGENT'. You can override
#> using the `.groups` argument.
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'ID'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#> # Groups:   ID [5]
#>      ID AGENT nyear
#>   <dbl> <chr> <int>
#> 1     2 A        14
#> 2     2 B         8
#> 3     7 A        34
#> 4     7 B        34
#> 5    15 A        29
#> 6    18 A        14
#> 7    18 D        39
#> 8    20 C        19
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! It also helped me resolve other problems that I had, thanks a lot!